# How to get GeoCoordinates from pictures in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an application which picks photo's from photo library using UIImagePicker. 
I want to read the geo-coordinates of the photo and use them in my application. 
Can you point me to any example code on how to do that ??

First of all is it possible to that ?? 
Any pointers to which classes I should use ??

Regards
HItesh V

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) library could be of assistance.